# How to disable option if current time or date is not met

Tags: php, mysqli

My question is that how can I disable options in the create drop down menu below if the start date `$dbSessionDate` and Start Time `$dbSessionTime` are before the current date and time?

Below is the drop down menu where data is fetched from database using mysqli:

```
while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {

$time_string = $dbSessionDate." ".$dbSessionTime;
$time_from_string = strtotime($time_string);    
if($time_from_string > date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
{
$sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;    
}else{
$sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' disabled>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;   

}
}
```

UPDATE:

HTML from view Source:

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='28'>LDREW - 09-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='29'>BQNYF - 10-01-2013 - 10:00</option>
<option value='22'>WDFRK - 17-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='26'>POKUB1 - 25-01-2013 - 15:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strtotime()`. Combine `$dbSessionDate` and `$dbSessionTime` together, pass it to the function `strtotime`, then compare the resultant variable to `date()`.

Code:

```
$time_string = $dbSessionDate." ".$dbSessionTime;
$time_from_string = strtotime($time_string);

if($time_from_string > strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")))
{
   //Do whatever you like to do.
}
```

Comment: Problem I am having is that it is disabling all options, I just want it to disable the relevant options, code updated in question

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: Posted html from view source in question. All options are not disabled when one option should be disabled

Comment: Alright..It is because the date function returns a string and strtotime returns a timestamp. Write it like this way: `if (strtotime($time_string) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))) ....`. I updated my code... Or you can use `time()` to get now and save yourself from trouble of `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need compare date and time and when its before the current date and time you need to put "disabled" attribute to dropdown.

Something like this:

```
while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
    $attribute = "";
    if (strtotime($dbSessionDate." ".$dbSessionTime) < date("Y-m-d H:i:s")){ $atribute = "disabled";}
    $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' %s>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $attribute, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here you can see disabled attribute definition:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp